# How to find the condition number of a 3*3 matrix with singular value 10, 1 and 1/10?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, condition-number

If the singular values of a 3*3  matrix  are 10, 1 and 1/10 respectively, what is the condition number of the matrix? Is such a matrix numerically tractable?

Answer (score 1):

the condition number of a matrix, $A$, with respect to a given matrix norm is:
$\kappa(A) = ||A||\cdot||A^{-1}||$.  in this case the singular values are the square root of the non-negative eigenvalues of $A^*A$, and the largest of them is the operator norm of $A$, so under this norm $||A|| = 10$ and $||A^{-1}|| = \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{-1} = 10$.  Thus the condition number, $\kappa(A) = ||A||\cdot||A^{-1}|| = 10\cdot 10 = 100$.  In general smaller condition numbers mean matrices are more tractable (Identity has condition number 1).  A condition number this high suggests conditioning is needed (SOR, Gauss-Sidel, etc).